# What is the maximum number of subdirectories allowed in Ext4?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I am considering moving my ext3 partition to ext4 in order to overcome the 32000 subdirectory limit.  I have seen two different numbers thrown around about the limits of ext4, both from reputable sources:

Limit of 64,000:

- [ext4.wiki.kernel.org](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Howto#EXT4_features)
- [SO ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/483040/if-i-upgrade-an-ext3-fs-to-ext4-will-it-automatically-increase-the-maximum-amou)

Unlimited:

- [Kernel Newbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/Ext4)
- [Kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2007/ols2007v2-pages-21-34.pdf)
- [SO SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/66331/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-folders-allowed-in-a-folder-in-linux)

What is the correct answer, and how can I determine the correct answer from the ext4 source?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The limit is 64000.  Until you enable the file system feature flag **dir_nlink**

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html

http://www.ispexperts.com.np/?p=797

Comment: In the (second) link that you are referencing, I's saying that it's 65,000 and not 64.000. Maybe it changed since 2014 but I'd rather update the accepted answer.